# Write huge XML file from DOM to file

Tags: java, xml, dom

I have a java program which queries a table which has millions of records and generates a xml with each record as node.

The challenge is that the program is running out of heap memory. I have allocated 2GB heap for the program.

I am looking for alternate approaches of creating such huge xml.

Can we write out partial DOM object to file and release the memory?
For eg, create 100 nodes in DOM object, write to file, release the memory, then create next 100 nodes in DOM etc

**Code to write a node to file**

```
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(node);
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
transformer.transform(source, result);
```

But how do I release the DOM memory after writing the nodes to file?

Comment: You should use SAX to parse xml instead of DOM.

Comment: I am not parsing any xml. I am creating xml.

Comment: Well, SAX is also what you need.

Comment: How to create nodes using SAX? I am not familiar with it.

Comment: This link has more info about xml processing. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/stax/why.html

Comment: use stax for xml writing http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbem.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need to generate a DOM? Try to write the XML directly. The most convenient API for outputting XML from Java is the StAX XMLStreamWriter interface. There are a number of implementations of XMLStreamWriter that generate lexical (serialized) XML, including the Saxon serializer which gives you considerable control over the way in which it is serialized (e.g. indentation and encoding) if you need it.

Comment: I am running on Java 5. Is there any API for Java 5 which does the same?

Comment: I think you can download a version of JAXP that includes StAX and runs on Java 5, but it may not be easy. Probably easier to hand-craft something similar of your own that calls a SAX ContentHandler underneath; the SAX ContentHandler interface is widely supported, but less easy to write to.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a simple OutputStreamWriter and format the xml by myself, you don't need to create a huge dom structure. I think this is the fastest way.

Of course depends on how much xml structure you want to accomplish. If one table row corresponds to one xml line, this should be the fastest way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

For processing a huge document, SAX is often preferred precisely because it keeps in memory only what you have explicitly decided to keep in memory -- which means you can use a specialized, and hence smaller, data model. For tasks such as this one, where you have no need to crossreference different parts of the document, you may not need any data model at all and can just generate SAX events directly from the input data and feed those into the serializer.

(StAX is pretty much equivalent in this regard. I usually prefer to stay with SAX since it's part of the JAXP API package and should be present in just about every Java environment at this point, but StAX may be a bit easier to work with.)

Comment: Websearching "DOM to SAX" will find examples of walking a DOM tree and generating SAX events from it. (And, probably, feeding those SAX events into a serializer to write out an XML-syntax file.) You might be able to apply a similar approach directly to your table.

Comment: I want to replace DOM with SAX. My requirement is to just create xml file from database records. I was doing DOM way now, which I want to replace with some better thing. I saw this article about writing xml using SAX `https://www.informit.com/library/content.aspx?b=STY_XML_21days&seqNum=221` . But this seems to be manual way of creating xml.

Comment: That's correct. SAX is an event model, not a data model. It handles reading XML syntax and writing XML syntax, but that's it -- it's your responsibility to feed it the data contents when writing out or accept and do something with the data when reading in.  The advantage for writing out is that it handles all the details and edge cases of XML syntax for you -- character escaping if needed, for example -- which generally makes it a better alternative than doing all the formatting yourself.

Comment: My aim is to just create an xml nothing else. So is it worth using SAX or can I manually create the xml using file IO? From the SAX samples I saw, what I understood is that we have to inherit from DefaultHandler and implement all the functions, which is similar to manual xml generation.

Comment: Depends. You can certainly do it manually, but then you have only yourself to blame if you get it wrong...